# Instagram sort posts by likes

Tags: instagram, har

I tried this method to sort Instagram posts by likes [This one](https://theuntoldapps.github.io/sorting-instagram-posts-by-likes/)

The problem is that I always get the same error.

`name@MacBook-Pro Insta % python sorter.py test.har 10 An error occurred: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 1048453 (char 1048452)`

I've tried everything but didn’t find any solution